# Adding class to div element based on JS calculated index

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, indexing

**I need a little help with the following:**
We're calculating custom index values for our items under a div element in JS.
We have the correct index value which we can see in the console, but we also need to assign a class to that particular indexed element so we can style it later on. How we can do that?

indexing for these particualr elements is based on the following code (once again, this is working but we have no idea how to add a class to the div container based on these indexes.. :/ )

The code is based on this btw:

```
let bestfitlist = [];
    const bestFitDisplay = bestfitlist.indexOf(Math.max(...bestfitlist))
```

**Our whole code looks like this:**

```
$(".product-container").slick({
    dots: false,
    infinite: false,
    nav:false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1
});

const allProducts = document.querySelectorAll(`.product-container .slick-track [data-min]`)
document.querySelector(`#range2`).addEventListener("change", slowHideProduct);

  function range(start, end, step = 1) {
    const len = Math.floor((end - start) / step) + 1
    return Array(len).fill().map((_, idx) => start + (idx * step))
  }
  
  function intersect(a, b) {
    return a.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(b));
  }

  
  function slowHideProduct(e){
    let selectedElements = [];
    let sliderInterval = [];
    let productTimeframe = [];
    let bestfitlist = [];
    const currentVal = parseInt(e.target.value);
    console.log(currentVal)
    for(let elem of allProducts) {
        const minsec = parseFloat(elem.dataset.min || 0);
        const maxsec = parseFloat(elem.dataset.max || 0);
        console.log("min sec" , minsec)
        console.log("max sec", maxsec)


        let sliderInterval = [...range(currentVal - 30,currentVal + 30,5)];
        console.log(sliderInterval);
        
        let productTimeframe = [...range(minsec,maxsec,5)];
        console.log(productTimeframe);
        
        let intersectionOfTime = intersect(sliderInterval,productTimeframe);
        console.log(intersectionOfTime);

        

          
      
        if(intersectionOfTime.length > 0) {
            selectedElements.push(elem);
            bestfitlist.push(intersectionOfTime.length);
        } else if(selectedElements.length == 0 && maxsec < Math.max(...sliderInterval)){
          selectedElements.push(elem);
        } else {
          sliderInterval = [];
          productTimeframe = [];
        }

        console.log(selectedElements)
        $(".product-container").slick('slickUnfilter')
        $(".product-container").slick('slickFilter',selectedElements)
    }
    console.log(bestfitlist)
    const bestFitDisplay = bestfitlist.indexOf(Math.max(...bestfitlist))
    console.log(bestFitDisplay)
    $(".item-container:eq(bestFitDisplay)").addClass("bestfit-active");
    
}

document.querySelector(`#range2`).dispatchEvent(new Event("change"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let bestfitlist = [];
    let bestFitDisplay = bestfitlist.indexOf(Math.max(...bestfitlist))
    //if bestfitlist[bestFitDisplay] is (html element) then :
    bestfitlist[bestFitDisplay].classList.add("someClassName")
```

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for the answer, bestFitDisplay  is not an HTML element, it's an index. We want to use this index to target a specific child element of an HTML element.

Comment: ok let me  know one thing does bestfitlist  contain html elements?

Comment: would bestfitlist[bestFitDisplay] give  html element?

Comment: I just edited the main question, pasting the whole code. Bestfitlist is an array of numbers.